# People who ask questions but do not accept answers

Tags: discussion

[This](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/236408/people-who-ask-questions-but-do-not-accept-answers) query, shows a list of users who ask question (more than 10Q) but never accept answers. Aprox 1k People.

I propose to give them the dark badge: "Holding a bag" or something funny.

Comment: There has never been a requirement here for people to accept answers. Would a badge for "people who complain because they don't get the rep they think they deserve" be a good idea as well? How about a badge for "most questions closed", or "most downvoted question"?

Comment: why not? a Dark badge! who claims, don't waste your time teaching me.

Comment: in fact there are a badge "Peer Pressure" ... that punish ignorance.

Comment: OK. I hereby award you the first ever "Bad suggestion for a badge" badge. Congratulations. Do you feel wonderful? (It's a step toward your goal to "punish ignorance".)

Comment: There is something odd about the empty check-mark that's displayed at the left of a post.  There are too many users that have no idea what it means.  I could theorize that it isn't visible enough or it is too much of a western symbol (there are a lot of Asian names in that list) but that would just be guessing.  Posting a helpful comment can easily solve that problem.

Comment: @Deuterium: Peer Pressure teaches you you have the option to delete your post if it turns out you were wrong. There is no 'punishment' there.

Answer (score 12):

Badges are generally used to *encourage* certain behaviors. This is not something we want to encourage.

Comment: That is clear, the thing is to call their attention.

Comment: prefers to be rigid?

Comment: You get the Scholar badge and points for accepting an answer. For peeople not interested in badges or points, a badge for not accepting answers won't have any positive effect.

Comment: Anyone else find it ironic that this answer hasn't been accepted.